# Getting Parent props inside Redux form child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

React Newbee Here using react redux and redux-form

I want to use data retrieved by `App.js` inside `Form.js` Currently I am passing `{this.props.data}` to `<Form />` I can't see or access the `App.js` props inside `<Form />` component , Instead I can just see reduxForm Props , How can I access `this.props.data` inside `<Form />` ?

I have a component where I am fetching the user data :

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import * as actions from "../actions";

import Form from "./Form";

class Questions extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchQuestion();
    }
    render() {
        return <Form formData={this.props.data} />;
    }
}
function mapStateToProps({ data }) {
    return { data };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Questions);
```

Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class renderForm extends Component {
  renderField({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
          <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
          {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="clubName"
          type="text"
          component={this.renderField}
          label="Club Name"
        />
        <FieldArray name="questions" component={this.renderQuestion} />
        <div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ data }) {
  return { data };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "fieldArrays"
})(connect(mapStateToProps, { actions })(FieldArraysForm));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you should only use the `reduxForm` HOC without connecting to redux (`connect()` wrapper) :

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: "fieldArrays"
})(renderForm);
```

In your form you can access the data from the parent using `this.props.formData`;

Comment: It gives me undefined two times , Can you please guide me how to check for undefined before sending down to `<Form >` ? maybe thats what causing this error

Comment: If you're taking about your redux `data` state it depends on the initial state you set in your `data` reducer, also what behaviour do you expect if data is undefined ?

Comment: I am talking about `return <Form formData={this.props.data} />;` inside App.js how can i only pass once there is a value inside `this.props.data` and not undefined ?

Comment: You can pass it conditionnaly like `formData={this.props.data && this.props.data}` but this is pointless because the result will be undefined too. You may want to pass default values like this : `formData={this.props.data ? this.props.data : { dataProp: 'defaultValue' }}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect your child component (form.js) to redux in this case as you are passing down the props from the parent component.

When you `mapSateToProps()` you are overriding the value of `this.props.data`.

Instead of

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: "fieldArrays"
})(connect(mapStateToProps, { actions })(FieldArraysForm));
```

Try

```
export default renderForm
```

EDIT:

Also, I think you should be exporting `renderForm` not `reduxForm`

Comment: When I change it to `export default renderForm` it gives me an error saying "Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()"